# i have integrate instagram api but not show all images

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my code for how show all images in my website??

I have already used limit function but it is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var userFeed = new Instafeed({
    get: "user",
    userId: "1750388asad4456544",
    limit: 1000,
    resolution: "standard_resolution",
    accessToken: "175038844.1677ed0.e54554175b89e9254445e42asd8a6b25b4fbaebe29",
    sortBy: "none",
    // popup image open
    // image
    // instagram open
    template:
      '<div class="col-lg-3 gallery instaimg">' +
      '<a href="{{link}}" title="{{caption}}" target="_blank">' +
      '<img src="{{image}}" alt="{{caption}}" class="img-fluid"></a></div>'
  });
  userFeed.run();

  $(".gallery").magnificPopup({
    type: "image",
    delegate: "a",
    gallery: {
      enabled: true
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly after read the documentation, you need a element with *instafeed* id.

*Instafeed.js with automatically look for a `<div id="instafeed"></div>` and fill it with linked thumbnails.*

Try this if you can.

Comment: my code in working but some images display in my website not all images show